# H2 postgresql dialect not working with using keyword

Tags: postgresql, h2

I am trying to cast a `text` type column in my postgres database to `oid` type with something like this

```
ALTER TABLE person ALTER COLUMN id TYPE oid USING id::oid; <--works in postgresql
```

But we use `h2` for our testing with `postgresql dialect` and it is not liking the `using` key. If I remove the `using` keyword the query works in `h2` but not in `postgres`

```
ALTER TABLE person ALTER COLUMN id TYPE oid; <--works in h2
```

Questions

1. Any way I can do this casting in postgresql without `using` keyword
2. OR any way I can make h2 recognize `using` keyword ?

Comment: https://phauer.com/2017/dont-use-in-memory-databases-tests-h2/

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name while I agree with all that.. it is not feasible to change years old testing setup in big companies because of one use case or incomptability..

Comment: According to this [H2 Alter Column](http://h2database.com/html/commands.html#alter_table_alter_column) you should be able to use: `SET DATA TYPE oid USING id::oid` or if the `::` shortcut does not work then `SET DATA TYPE oid USING CAST(id as oid)` . This syntax also works in Postgres [PG Alter Column](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html)

Comment: @AdrianKlaver thx.. I tried both but Keep getting error `Syntax error in SQL statement "`     `ALTER TABLE PERSON ALTER COLUMN ID SET DATA TYPE OID USING[*] CAST(ID AS OID)"; SQL statement:` notice the `*` on `using` keyword

Comment: I don't use `H2` so I don't have anything to test on this end. That syntax works on Postgres end though and according to `H2` grammar should work on that end as well. Seems like something that needs to be filed as an [Issue](https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues).

Comment: Ok..had to dig into h2 codebase.. found this commit https://github.com/h2database/h2database/commit/fafb66cc394d007797714b49e1de58adb88b2de3  looks like support for `using` was added in v2.1.210

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](https://github.com/h2database/h2database/commit/%E2%80%A6) commit looks like support for `using` keyword was added in following versions

```
version-2.1.210  version-2.0.206 version-2.0.204 version-2.0.202
```